# Unity - LoadLevelAsync hiccups on scene switch

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a loading animation while using LoadLevelAsync to load the next scene.

The loading animation is a loading circle that continuously rotates in the middle of the screen, and I use LoadLevelAsync("NextScene") in the code. The problem is that every time right before the scene switch happens the circle will freeze for a few milliseconds before the next scene appears.

I do know that the less things the next scene contains, the shorter the freeze is, but I thought that LoadLevelAsync's purpose was for letting the user experience no lag during scene transitions. My next scene contains a background sprite, some buttons, scripts, and a 3MB audio file. The screen will always freeze for half a second before showing the next scene.

I am using Unity 4.6.3 with Pro feature. I'm also testing the results on a device. I have also tried out the AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation with Coroutines, and unfortunately they don't work.

If anyone has a solution, or has any suggestions on smooth scene transitions, I would greatly appreciate them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of the components in your new scene will get `Awake` and `Start` calls, which could easily cause a hiccup that's hard to avoid. If you need to resolve that, you could try to spread initialization over multiple frames via coroutines, but it's going to be a pile of work.

Comment: i agree with rutter - you can try it for yourself - make an empty scene and add a few of your objects that don't use Awake and Start (or comment out these functions) and you will see the difference.

Comment: Thanks rutter and JinJi!
I will try to look for or create a custom loader/deleter then.
Thank you!